# Add date format into date regex

Tags: angularjs, date

I am getting date format like this `/Date(1495111091673)/`.
I have created one custom filter to change date format.

```
app.filter('jsonDate', function () {
    return function (date) {
        return new Date(date.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
    }
})
```

This filter returns date like this.

```
Thu May 18 2017 18:08:11 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

But I want it as standard format like `dd/MM/yyyy` so I have edited my filter code like this:

```
app.filter('jsonDate', function () {
    return function (date) {
        return new Date(date.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1, 'dd MMMM @ HH:mm:ss');
    }
})
```

Is it correct?

Comment: Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com): `moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY')`

Answer (score 1):

> This filter returns date like this
>   *Thu May 18 2017 18:08:11 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)*

No it doesn't, that's just how your console (or whatever) is choosing to display the `Date` instance (via `Date.prototype.toString()`).

I'd just use AngularJS's `date` filter ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date.

For example (where `dateFormat` is your `"/Date(1495111091673)/"` formatted string)

```
{{dateFormat | jsonDate | date : 'shortDate'}}
```

---

Or in JS

```
let parsed = $filter('jsonDate')(dateFormat)
let dateString = $filter('date')(parsed, 'shortDate')
```

or via DI

```
.controller('controllerName', ['dateFilter', 'jsonDateFilter',
function(dateFilter, jsonDateFilter) {
  let dateString = dateFilter(jsonDateFilter(dateFormat), 'shortDate')
}])
```

Comment: Your answer is for html.But I am trying to do it in controller.

Comment: @krish then use the JavaScript API mentioned in the documentation

Comment: I have sent like this `$scope.filterStartDate = $filter('jsonDate')(/Date(1495111091673)/, 'yyyy / MM / dd');`. and its returning this format only `Thu May 18 2017 18:08:11 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Comment: @krish yeah, because that totally looks like what I've got in my answer. You haven't quoted your strings, nor does your `jsonDate` filter accept more than **one argument**

Comment: Yes, and just like I said in my answer, **use Angular's `date` filter**. You also appear to be passing a regular expression as the first argument which doesn't make sense

Comment: How can I pass custom filter for `ng-model` ? here is my code `<input ng-model="currentLeave.fromDate" json-date="{{currentLeave.fromDate}}"/>` Its not working.